# How to convert nested Dictionary to JSON string

Tags: python, json

I try to convert a nested dictionary to JSON string

```
a = {'default': {'version': 1.0, 'db': 'mangodb', 'uuid': 'eaada7dc-ec30-4548-a080-c4f70293202a'}, 'temperatures': [{1: 50}, {2: 100}]}

a_json = json.dumps(a['temperature'])
print(a_json)
```

I was expecting to have 
`{1: 50}, {2: 100}`, but when I executed this code, I had `[[null, {"1": 50}], {"2": 100}]]`

How can I get a result without this null?

Comment: `temperature` should be `temperatures`.

Comment: The result you expect is not valid JSON. A JSON array needs `[]` around it. But I can't see where `null` is coming from.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I use `a_json = json.dumps(a['temperatures'])` I get `[{"1": 50}, {"2": 100}]`.

Comment: `json.dumps()` will produce `null` for Python `None`.

Comment: Can't replicate the problem as well, except to change `temperature` to `temperatures`. Got ouptut `[{"1": 50}, {"2": 100}]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
import json

a = {'default': {'version': 1.0, 'db': 'mangodb', 'uuid': 'eaada7dc-ec30-4548-a080-c4f70293202a'}, 'temperatures': [{1: 50}, {2: 100}]}

with open('out.json', mode='w+') as f:
    a_json = json.dump(a['temperatures'], f)
```

Also, in case you don't want to use an output file:

```
import json

a = {'default': {'version': 1.0, 'db': 'mangodb', 'uuid': 'eaada7dc-ec30-4548-a080-c4f70293202a'}, 'temperatures': [{1: 50}, {2: 100}]}

a_json = json.dumps(a['temperatures'])
print(a_json)
```

I have tested both samples and they appear to be working just fine.